# MS Access input mask exclamation point

Tags: validation, ms-access

I've reading many explanation online but will could not figure out how exclamation point (!) affects MS Access displays data. From [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-HA010096452.aspx), it defines ! as

> Causes the input mask to fill from left to right instead of from right to left.

I know this is not entirely right because ! doesn't not affect how data is **entered**, it affect how data is **displayed**.

In [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114880), ! was explained but not very clear. It says:

```
For example, if you type the number 5550248 into the following input mask examples, the characters fill from left to right as you type them. However, when you press ENTER to accept the data, the results are displayed as follows: 
   Input Mask                     Result
   -------------------------------------------
   !\(999") "999\-9999;;_         ( ) 555-0248
   \(999") "999\-9999;;_          (555) 024-8
```

From what I can see, the one with ! does not to fill from left to right. Otherwise, it should fill the first 9, which should result (555) 024-8.

I also found [this link](http://www.teacherclick.com/access2003/a_5_1_2.htm), which says

> Causes the input mask to display from right to left rather then from left to right.

But it's for Access 2003. I don't think the definition of "!" has been changed. I just want to know exactly how "!" is defined in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how an electronic calculator displays numbers as they are entered... that's what it does.